# jquery .unbind and .bind not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to bind and unbind the following, depending on what button is clicked. Here's what happens first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.xxMenu > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
[... etc.]
</script>
```

That makes some drop-down menus function. In the next script, if I put either of the following, they work fine to unbind the above and thus disable the menus when a search button is clicked:

```
 $('.xxMenu > li').unbind('mouseover');
 $('.xxMenu > li').unbind();
```

This, I notice by the way, doesn't work to unbind:

```
 $('.xxMenu > li').unbind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
```

Now, in the script after that, if I put any of the following they don't restore, i.e. re-bind, the first one (when someone clicks a button to cancel the search). Here's the whole script in this case:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.closeSearch > img').bind('click', closeSearchBar);

    function closeSearchBar() {
        $('form.xxx').css('visibility', 'hidden');  
        $('.closeSearch > img').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.searchIcon > img').css('visibility', 'visible');

          /* the ones that aren't working */
          $('.xxMenu > li').bind();
          /* or */
          $('.xxMenu > li').bind('mouseover');
          /* or */
          $('.xxMenu > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);        
       };          
     });
   </script>
```

I'm wondering where the syntax or the logic is wrong, looking [at this](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) but haven't been able to figure it out.

**UPDATE:** Here's the whole thing on request. Sorry, I thought I was saving everyone some time by just posting the important parts. Fairly new at this.

```
<!-- 
Activate Drop Down Menus 
-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.xxMenu > li').on('mouseover', openSubMenu);
    $('.xxMenu > li').on('mouseout', closeSubMenu);

    function openSubMenu() {
        $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');    
    };

    function closeSubMenu() {
        $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
    };

});
</script>


<!-- 
Open search field
-->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.searchIcon > img').on('click', showSearch);

    function showSearch() {
        $('.search-macro .search-macro-query input').css('width', '533px');
        $('form.aui').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
        $('form.aui').css('z-index', '15');
        $('.closeSearch > img').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.search-macro-button').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.searchIcon > img').css('visibility', 'hidden'); 

          /* disable the drop-down menus */
          $('.xxMenu > li').off('mouseover');

    };                         
});
</script>


<!-- 
Close search field when X button is clicked
-->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.closeSearch > img').on('click', closeSearchBar);

    function closeSearchBar() {
        $('form.aui').css('visibility', 'hidden');  
        $('.closeSearch > img').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.searchIcon > img').css('visibility', 'visible');
                    /* re-enable the drop-down menus if search is canceled */
        $('.xxMenu > li').on('mouseover', openSubMenu);
    };         
});
</script>


 <!-- 
 Show live search button when any search input typed in the field
 -->

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('form.aui').on('keypress', changeImgs);

  function changeImgs() {
  $('.closeSearch > img').css('visibility', 'hidden');

  $('.aui-button').css({'z-index':'12', 'visibility':'visible', 'position':'relative', 'left':'292px', 'border':'0px','border-radius':'0px', 'background':'url(http://ops.confluence.uat.apg.services.gs.com:18090/download/attachments/38109760/searchPrompt.gif?version=5&modificationDate=1413553110523&api=v2) no-repeat'});

  $('input.text').css({'border':'0px'});

  /*   Hide the gray Confluence search submit button   */
  $('.searchbar > div > form > fieldset > button > span').css({'visibility':'hidden'})


 };
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.

Comment: What do you mean by *"in the script after that"* - both your scripts seems to be in `ready()`, so the order isn't likely to affect... Can you provide the entire code, rather than throwing few bits here and there..? Where exactly are you unbinding..?

Comment: I guess `openSubMenu()` function isn't on global scope. Are you declaring it inside `ready` handler?

Comment: TJ I didn't mean "after" to imply that, I could have just as easily said "in another script". The only order involved is that someone could only activate the second script after the button triggered by the first script appears. I'll clean up/anonymize the whole thing and post it.

Comment: A Wolff: Well, as shown at the top. Does that answer the question? Not sure. Thx

Comment: j98691: Ok thanks, I read up on that and just changed all .bind and .unbind to .on .off -- which works, thanks, good to know. The same problem as before though, that last .on/.bind isn't doing anything.

Comment: @user3762977 No it doesn't answer the question where are you declaring `openSubMenu()` function. Any error in console? Why don't you post relevant code rather than `few bits here and there`???

Comment: Following update, just declare functions outside ready handler scope. FYI, you should debug code using your console

Comment: A. Wolff - I thought I had included that next line in the original, my bad. I've posted the whole thing now.

Comment: A Wolff: That did it, thx. Others have suggested in the past that putting the solution as an answer that I can accept will be useful, so I did. (I can't mark my own answer as accepted until two days have passed, however.)

Answer (score 2):

This answer from comments fixed it:

"just declare functions outside ready handler scope"

Just putting as an answer in case it's useful to others. A basic question I know, but still.

Comment: Good you taking time to fix it and answer it ;)

Comment: A: Thx. Sheesh, rough crowd! -2 for being confused ;) And confusing, I suppose, more to the point. Thx again.